# New to Prototypal Inheritance - Can't find the issue with Undefined variable

Tags: javascript

I'm quite new to Prototypal inheritance in JavaScript and I'm trying to understand what's the issue here.

Simple code, we have two objects pet and pet2, pet2 inherits from pet.

```
var Pet = function() {
    this.type="Dog";
    this.age = 4;
};

var Pet2 = function() {
    this.breed = "Kashon";
};

pet = new Pet();
pet2 = new Pet2();


if (Object.create !==  'function') {
    Object.create = function(oldObject) {
        function F() {}
        F.prototype = oldObject;
        return new F();
    };    
}

pet2 = Object.create(pet);
```

The issue is that when I try to access **pet2.breed**, it's undefined for some reason, why is this?

```
alert(pet2.type); //ok
alert(pet2.age);  //ok
alert(pet2.breed); //comes out undefined?
```

Any help would be nice :D

Answer (score 3):

When you use use Object.create you are assigning old object as prototype (eg, Pet). Of course, no properties of Pet2 would be there. You should "inherit" objects using prototype like: `Pet2.prototype = new Pet;`

```
var Pet = function() {
  this.type="Dog";
  this.age = 4;
};

var Pet2 = function() {
  this.breed = "Kashon";
};
Pet2.prototype = new Pet; // Pet2 inherits Pet

pet = new Pet();
pet2 = new Pet2();

alert(pet2.type); //ok
alert(pet2.age);  //ok
alert(pet2.breed); // ok?
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U66aX/

Comment: I was going to post this in my answer also, since it was the smallest change to the OP's code. I didn't because you'd be mixing pseudo-classical and prototypal inheritance. `Object.create` is supposed to obviate the need for setting the prototype chain using `SubClass.prototype = new SuperClass`, or at least hide it in the implementation of `Object.create`... Actually, I just noticed this doesn't even use Object.create, which was kind of the point of the OP's question, wasn't it?

Comment: Not sure I understand where it is the mixing of pseudo-classical and prototypal inheritance? In my answer there just pure prototyping, no?

Comment: Yes, I noticed it after, so my comment after the ... was supposed to explain it. I assumed you would end up using `Object.create` to create an object that inherits from Pet2 but, you just used `new` which is what all the `Object.create` purists object to. I particularly think this (pseudo-classical) is the best way to do it (give me constructors), I just don't think it answers the question, though it solves the problem... Sorry, even my head is spinning after my explanation.

Comment: You say the right things. In my case I just not familiar enough with Object.create (I started when it hadn't existed, and then became MooTools with built-in classic-like inheritance scheme, which I primarily use now). So, thanks for valuable comments, friend.

Comment: By the way, there is a problem with setting up inheritance by doing `SubClass.prototype = new SuperClass`. If you're curious, check my post http://js-bits.blogspot.com/2010/08/javascript-inheritance-done-right.html

Answer (score 2):

A number of problems here.

- You are mixing pseudo-classical with prototypal inheritance. Not that it can't be done, but I would stick with one of them only. Since you're asking about prototypal, you should stay away from `new` (except inside your `Object.create` function)
- You are setting pet2 twice, therefore overriding your initial assignment that made it an instance of `Pet2`.
- You're never saying that `Pet2` inherits from `Pet1`

Here's what the prototypal example would look like: http://jsfiddle.net/NsRMA/

```
var Pet1 = {
  type: "Dog",
  age: 4
};

// Make Pet2 inherit from Pet1
var Pet2 = Object.create(Pet1);
// Add new properties to Pet2, this can and should be done 
// by passing another argument to Object.create , but any 
// hacked version can't support it
Pet2.breed = "Kashon";

// Now create an object that inherits from Pet2 (and consequently, Pet1)
var pet = Object.create(Pet2);

alert(pet.type); //ok
alert(pet.age);  //ok
alert(pet.breed); //ok
```

Comment: Since new is not being used at all, does this mean I should not use constructor functions and just use object literals when inheriting? I apologize if these are silly questions, still new to it :)

Comment: If you like this style, yes. But I prefer using new, object.create is not as intuitive for object initialization